# PHP timestamp format sent to csv

Tags: php, csv, timestamp

I am a php newbie and need some guidance.

I have a simple form online capturing answers to five questions, this data is then sent via the code below to a csv for my client to download and import. I needed a timestamp appended to the information being saved which I have investigated and dropped in the code.

Unfortunately the csv shows the timestamp as 40235.52555, Importing this into Excel and formatting the column shows the date correctly but I need the csv to also show it as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

I'm presuming the code for the timestamp I'm using is incorrect for this to happen. Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

```
    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {
        header('location: thankyou.html');
    } else {
        header('location: vpg-form.php');
    }
    { 
        $expectations = $_POST["Expectations"]; 
        $acknowledged = $_POST["Acknowledged"]; 
        $clubhouse = $_POST["Clubhouse"]; 
        $app = $_POST["App"];
        $experience = $_POST["Experience"];

        if(empty($expectations)||empty($acknowledged)||empty($clubhouse)||empty($app)||empty($experience)) 
        { 
            echo "ERROR MESSAGE"; 
            die; 
        } 
        $cvsData =''.PHP_EOL; 
        $cvsData .= "\"$expectations\",\"$acknowledged\",\"$clubhouse\",\"$app\",\"$experience\",\"$datetime=now()\"".PHP_EOL; 
        $fp = fopen("vpg.csv", "a"); 

        if($fp) 
        { 
            fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file 
            fclose($fp); // Close the file 
        }     
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a date() function:

manual: PHP date() [php.net/manual/en/function.date.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

It takes a "format" argument first, and an optional timestamp argument (Default is now()).

So I guess you need something like:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Outputs:

2014-02-27 13:57:00

Comment: Hi Hawkeye, thanks for your idea. Unfortunately it didn't work for me, all I got back in the csv was the string - date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); I know I'm probably doing something really stupid and not dropping it in the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First answer is good.  I think the now() function returns a timestamp (numeric value) which is then being converted to a string on the CSV file.  Using the date object allows you to output a string-formatted date value.  PHP website at php.net has a very good online searchable manual.  Good luck and cheers Hawkeye for a simple answer.  I would vote you up but I can't yet!